# How do I customize the layout of products on a category page? I want all rows and no columns with a small pic and the ability to input quantities

Tags: magento2, layout

I want to decrease the amount of space a product takes up on the catalog page.

I don't want grid or list view. I want the customer to be able to see 100 products per page listed as if they were in rows of excel.

Product name - Very small picture - description - text box for quantity.

I'm having trouble finding the proper html files folks speak of on forums, have looked through themes and extensions. Can someone explain the scope of what I'm trying to accomplish, where it is to be performed and in pretty simple language. I'm kind of a beginner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Comment: From the comments below it's obviously Magento 2, I tagged the question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The template file that renders the category page is in

```
app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

Keep in mind that altering this file will change the category page, the search result page and others.

Comment: when I navigate to app/design/frontend the only folder I've got to choose from is Magento. Is this becaue I haven't added a theme? I've been working with magento blank and magento luma. Would installing a different theme populate these directories? /YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/catalog/product/list.phtml  ??

Comment: as I aksed above "which magento version are you using?" I was referring to magento 1.x. Please clearly state your Magento version in your question